# Dockerfile does not replace text but command line does, possible bug?

Tags: bash, docker, sed, dockerfile

I have a simple Dockerfile that copies over a template which I used `sed` to replace some of the variables. Pretty straight forward. Looks very doable and from what I've seen/read for all intents and purposes, it *should* do it.

```
COPY /my-dir/my-textfile.conf /to/my/docker/path.conf
RUN sed -i s:TEXTTOREPLACE:my-new-text:g /to/my/docker/path.conf
```

I then run `docker build....` then `docker run ... bash`
then I `cat` my file and `TEXTTOREPLACE` is still there.

Run the same `sed` command in the bash and it works no problem.

Any thoughts? What am I doing wrong/not seeing?

Thanks! 
EDIT per request: base image is `debian:7.11`, work station is MAC OSX

Comment: @eLRuLL updated.

Comment: In fact it works e.g. starting FROM ubuntu:latest. I tried it just removing leading / from source copy argument (because I tred using a file in my working directory) and copying the file to /tmp, just to do a quick test.

Comment: yes Kevin, this mostly looks like a problem with the path of your local file `/my-textfile.conf` is that file really in the root folder?

Comment: ah no sorry, its in /etc/..../myconfig.conf not in root.

Comment: @gile Can you try it via `debian:7.11`? and see if you get the same result?

Comment: On Linux it works as expected also starting FROM debian:7.11. Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4. I can't test on MAC OSX.

Comment: @gile You're saying in the `COPY` command remove the leading `/`? That did not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to recap.

- I have the file `my-textfile.conf` in my working directory. Its content is:

> I need to change TEXTTOREPLACE with my-new-text

- My test system is Ubuntu Linux 16.04 running Docker version 18.09.0, build
  4d60db4.
- This is the Dockerfile

`FROM debian:7.11
COPY my-textfile.conf /tmp/path.conf
RUN sed -i s:TEXTTOREPLACE:my-new-text:g /tmp/path.conf`

I run the following commands:

```
docker build -t mytestimage .
docker run -ti -d --name mytestcontainer mytestimage
docker exec -ti mytestcontainer /bin/bash
```

Then, inside the container, I run:

```
cat /tmp/path.conf
```

and I get this result:

> I need to change my-new-text with my-new-text

So it seems it works as expected.

Comment: Hmm, you're right it does work in this example, must be something else I'm doing in the rest of this dockerfile that isn't letting it change. Thanks for guinea pigging @gile

Comment: @Kevin I tried the same thing as gile on OSX, and it works.